# Translation needed for 130 years old church document

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

[image]

I found this record of my great grandfather in a local church in Malaysia. Today, nobody use Latin anymore in this country. I should be much grateful if someone can help my family translating this document so that we can trace our root. My great grandfather's name on the certificate is Lam Fuk On.

Comment: I posted my translation, but the handwriting is a bit difficult: if you know what the fifth line is supposed to say, a transcription would be helpful. (The first thing on that line is a person's name.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a record of a baptism, stating:

- the date of the event (17 of April of 1887), which was four days after the baby was born
- the minister officiating the ceremony ([Father F.P. Sorin](https://www.facebook.com/i1travel/photos/a.471589612877264/471590776210481/?type=3&theater), a French missionary priest, buried at St. Anne's Church, [just a few miles away](https://binged.it/2H0gMw9) from the church where the baptism took place) (more info about the priest [here](http://butterworthguide.com.my/index.php/bukit-mertajam/95-church-of-st-anne-monument-to-faith-and-antiquity))
- the place (the extinct [Church of the Sacred Heart of Jesus](https://www.penang-traveltips.com/catholic-church-of-the-sacred-heart-of-jesus.htm), in Machang Bubok)
- the name of the parents
- the Christian name given to the baby (*Justinus*, or Justin, in English)
- the name of the godparents (fifth line)

Comment: Isn't Lam Fuk On the name of the father? Specifically, the line looks like "filium legitimum Lam Fuk On et Virginiae"; my guess is both names are genitive, but "Lam Fuk On" is indeclinable.

Comment: Woah, nice findings!

Comment: You actually found the priest in question?? Damn, impressive!

Comment: @Draconis No merit for me. Google did the finding!

Comment: I almost fell down from my chair seeing your findings. I am really amazed that you managed to track the details of Father F.P Sorin. The St Anne's Church is a globally well-known church (for its annual St Anne's Feast) near our community. This is also where my father's ash is sealed. I have never thought the Church of the Sacred Heart of Jesus is the abandoned/ruined church that I know. Our ancestors (at least 5 generations) are mainly buried here.

Comment: Lam Fuk On is the father of the baptized child. The wife's name on the certificate is Virginia. But next to Lam Fuk On's grave, the wife's name is Agnes. I know my great grandfather had many women and lived like a king. That's why he didn't leave anything behind for us. LOL.

Comment: @luchonacho Thank you from the bottom of my heart. Your finding is really something big to me.

Comment: @LawrenceL Amazing stuff! I'm happy to have helped a bit. Praise be to God!

Comment: @Draconis Yes, Lam Fuk On is the name of the father. Unfortunately, due to the incomplete ancestry records, I failed to find out who "Justinus" really is. I will try to dig for the baptism records of my other grand-uncles. I hope I can solve the mystery one day.

Answer (score 17):

This looks like a standard baptism record.

> In the Year of Our Lord 1887, on the 17th day of the month of April, in this church of the Most Sacred Heart of Jesus in Machang-Bubok, I, Sorin, M. Ap., solemnly baptized the legitimate son of Lam Fuk On and Virginia, born four days ago; the name "Justinus" was given to him. Mian Ah Vu(?) and his wife, Lam Charlotte, were named as his godparents. [Signed,] F. Sorin.

I'm having a bit of difficulty with the handwriting, so I'm not sure I got the priest's name right, and I'm not even able to make a good guess at the godfather's name: it's the first handwritten thing on the fifth line.

Comment: @luchonacho From the context, I took the name as being in the genitive: compare to "et Virginiae" right after it.

Comment: Makes sense like that. Actually, when the OP says "my great grandfather's name on the certificate is Lam Fuk On" I took it to mean the person being baptised, but I see it refers to the parent of the baby.

Comment: The fifth line seems to include the Latin words "fuerunt" and "ejus uxor": Lam Charlotte would be the wife of... err... Mian On Vu?, the godfather. _Vero_ in the first line seems to me like a (stylistic?) connector that doesn't really need to be included in the translation, as sometimes happens with _autem_ too.

Comment: The first letter in the second word in the godfather's name matches the A in _Aprilis_, so it could be [Mian?] An [Vu?]

Comment: @Rafael That's as good a reading as any, and certainly better than mine! Added that tentatively to the translation.

Comment: The "an/on/en vu" might actually be French (priest was French) "en vu", which would mean as much as "in sight". So then we get for the fifth line: "The godfathers were Mian, present, and Lam Charlotte, his wife".

Comment: @HolKann That's an interesting idea! But Rafael's comparison to the first letter in "Aprilis" is convincing, and I'm not sure the priest would use French in an otherwise Latin document.

Comment: Dear all, thanks for helping my family translating this 130 years old document. We really appreciate your help as nobody speaks Latin anymore in this country. The name is actually "Ah Vu" which is a Chinese name. But the one looks like "Imian" in front I can't figure out. But I am sure it is a Chinese surname.

Comment: The fifth line seems to include the Latin words "fuerunt" and "ejus uxor": I was told that "eijus uxor" means — HIS WIFE. What about "fuerunt" (which appears before the name of Lam Fuk On?

Comment: @LawrenceL sorry for the omission, __fuerunt__ is simply the verb: the godparents _were_ Xxxxx Ah Vu and Lam Charlotte.